# How to break while loop either with timeout or condition is fullfiled?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I want to create a while loop where it will break, whenever timeout finish or condition is  fulfilled

```
async checkFile (filePath) {
    const readDir =  fs.readdirSync(filePath,'utf-8')
    while(true) {
        if(readDir === filename) {
            break;
        }
        
    } 
}
```

Comment: Use `Promise.any()` with two Promises, one being "the condition is fulfilled" and the other being "time is up". The `Promise.any()` will resolve when either of them is done.

Comment: What timeout? What condition - both `true` and `readDir` are constant during your loop? What is `filename`?

Comment: ... why an async approach (the OP's timeout, the suggested promise) anyhow when the reading method suggest otherwise ... `fs.readdirSync`? ... how about ... `filenames = fs.readdirSync(filePath,'utf-8'); filenames.forEach(file => console.log(file));` (I'm not a  node.js file system specialist)

Comment: your first line is missing a `function` keyword after `async`. Unless it's a method from a class. There are three ways to accomplish your task, using a promise that is resolved when either the file is found or the timeout is hit. If you have non-blocking actions inside your loop, you can set a timeout to change the while condition. You can also have a check inside your loop to see if time has passed from the start of your loop.

Comment: Maybe the OP also considers looking into [Node's File system documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirsyncpath-options)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?
Creating a start date var, then having the condition to loop be that the current date - the start date is less than 1000 (ms) or whatever timeout you would prefer

```js
async checkFile(filePath) {
    const readDir =  fs.readdirSync(filePath,'utf-8');
    const start = new Date();
    while ((new Date()) - start < 1000) {
        if(readDir === filename) {
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I will add that if you are using a loop like this for busy waiting, it's not ideal in js. Busy waiting is expensive, resource heavy. It would be better to have a promise that resolved when the condition is met.